# Regular Expressions in a dataframe Python

Tags: python, regex, dataframe

I am trying to extract the name from the data frame.

```
df.['target_name'].head()

3                             Minnie
4     Albert [unclear]Gles[/unclear]
5      Eliza [unclear]Gles[/unclear]
6                      John Slaltery
7     [unclear]P.[/unclear] Slaltery
23     ? Stewart
34                     John Maddison
35                     Herbert Olney
36                   William Iverach
37               [unclear][/unclear]
38                  Peter Blacksmith
39                    William Oliver
40                             Emily
Name: target_name, dtype: object
```

This is the output. We just want to get rid of the unnecessary characters and fetch the name. 
This is what I have done:

```
import re
df['target_name'] = df['target_name'].astype(str) #converting it into a string.
```

I tried using these two methods, but the both gave me the same output i.e. Nan

```
df['target_name'] = df['target_name'].str.extract('([a-zA-Z ]+)', expand=False).str.strip()
df['target_name3'] = df['target_name'].str.replace(r'\([^)]*\)', '').str.strip()
```

Comment: Try `df['target_name'] = df['target_name'].astype(str).replace(r'^\W+|\[[^][]*]', '')`

Comment: Hi thanks for your prompt reply, but it does not do any changes.

Comment: Even if `df['target_name3'] = df['target_name'].astype(str).str.replace(r'^\W+|\[[^][]*]', '')`?

Comment: giving the same output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work for me.

```
import pandas as pd
import re
target_name = ["Minnie", "Albert [unclear]Gles[/unclear]", 
               "Eliza [unclear]Gles[/unclear]", 
               "[unclear]P.[/unclear] Slaltery",  "? Stewart"]
df = pd.DataFrame(target_name, columns = ['target_name'])
df['target_name'] = df['target_name'].astype('str').str.replace(r'\/|\?','').str.replace('\[[a-z]+\]','').str.strip()
```

Comment: Thanks, that works for me too. There is an entry that has a question mark next to it. It doesn't get rid of that.

Comment: I have modified the code to remove the "?" as well. Add a side note, please always try to provide an example that others can run easily.